# What's the most efficient way to iterate by rows for each group of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering how to efficiently loop through rows by groups. So like the following sample dataset shows, it includes 3 different students with their pass records in 3 months.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'student':'A A A B B B C C C'.split(),
                  'month':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                  'pass':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})
print(df)
 student  month  pass
0       A      1     0
1       A      2     1
2       A      3     0
3       B      1     0
4       B      2     0
5       B      3     0
6       C      1     1
7       C      2     0
8       C      3     0
```

I'd like to have a new column "pass_patch", which should be equal to "pass" at first. But when a student has "pass" as 1 then all of his "pass_patch" in the following months should be 1, like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student':'A A A B B B C C C'.split(),
                   'month':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'pass':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'pass_patch':[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
print(df)
  student  month  pass  pass_patch
0       A      1     0           0
1       A      2     1           1
2       A      3     0           1
3       B      1     0           0
4       B      2     0           0
5       B      3     0           0
6       C      1     1           1
7       C      2     0           1
8       C      3     0           1
```

I did some searches and found iterrows might work, but was concerned it would be too slow to run for the whole dataset (around million of records). Would there be more efficient ways to realize that?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `cummax`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('student')['pass'].cummax()
df
Out[78]: 
  student  month  pass  new
0       A      1     0    0
1       A      2     1    1
2       A      3     0    1
3       B      1     0    0
4       B      2     0    0
5       B      3     0    0
6       C      1     1    1
7       C      2     0    1
8       C      3     0    1
```

Comment: Thanks Beny! It's both simple and efficient

Answer (score 3):

> What's the most efficient way to iterate by rows for each group of
> rows

#### DON'T ITERATE MANUALLY

Manualy iteration should always be your last option to try, most often, there's always some better way to perfrom a required operation rather than doing the iteration.

You can groupby `student`, then call `cumsum` which will just sum the values iteratively, convert it to boolean then convert it back to int:

```py
df['pass_patch'] = df.groupby('student')['pass'].cumsum().astype(bool).astype(int)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```py
  student  month  pass  pass_patch
0       A      1     0           0
1       A      2     1           1
2       A      3     0           1
3       B      1     0           0
4       B      2     0           0
5       B      3     0           0
6       C      1     1           1
7       C      2     0           1
8       C      3     0           1
```

**PS:** In above solution, you can avoid `.astype(bool).astype(int)` part if there is not more than one 1s for pass for each group. You may also need to sort the dataframe on months for each student if they are not sorted, I have not added that part since the sample data you have provided is already in that order.

Comment: You get the same result without using `astype`, what's the reasoning?

Comment: @blorgon, if there are multiple 1s for the same group, then value will be greater than 1, that is why conversion to bool and back to int has been used

Comment: Ah, I'd suggest using `clip()` if having multiple 1s in a group is a possibility, as that would achieve the same effect without casting twice, which could be expensive (I haven't tested this).

Comment: Nice solution! Here you are assuming students and months are already sorted. For the general case I suggest to add `df.sort_values(["student", "month"])` before the groupby.

Comment: @rpanai the solution is obviously based on the sample data OP has provided

Comment: That's why I said for the general case ;)

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the editing!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace 0 by `pd.NA` and then use `ffill` method, and then replace the null values back to 0:

```py
df['pass_patch'] = df['pass'].replace(0, pd.NA)
df['pass_patch'] = df.groupby('student')['pass_patch']\
                    .transform(lambda x: x.ffill())\
                    .fillna(0)\
                    .astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  student  month  pass  pass_patch
0       A      1     0           0
1       A      2     1           1
2       A      3     0           1
3       B      1     0           0
4       B      2     0           0
5       B      3     0           0
6       C      1     1           1
7       C      2     0           1
8       C      3     0           1
```

Comment: Nice one. I just formatted your answer and converted to `int`.

Comment: Thanks, @rpanai! I don't think it's necessary, though, because I used `pd.NA` instead of `np.nan`, which doesn't automatically change from `int` to `float` as this last one does.

Comment: I guess it depends on your pandas version. Using version 1.0.4 I got floats

Comment: Yeah, might be! Thanks for letting me now!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'student':'A A A B B B C C C'.split(),
                  'month':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                  'pass':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})
```

First we search the month of first pass for students that actually passed at least once.

```py
grp = df[df["pass"].eq(1)]\
    .sort_values(["student", "month"])\
    .groupby("student").head(1)
```

where `grp` looks like

```sh
  student  month  pass
1       A      2     1
6       C      1     1
```

Then we merge the dataframes

```py
df = pd.merge(df, 
              grp,
              on=["student"],
              how="left",
              suffixes=(None, '_y'))
```

and `df` looks like

```sh
  student  month  pass  month_y  pass_y
0       A      1     0      2.0     1.0
1       A      2     1      2.0     1.0
2       A      3     0      2.0     1.0
3       B      1     0      NaN     NaN
4       B      2     0      NaN     NaN
5       B      3     0      NaN     NaN
6       C      1     1      1.0     1.0
7       C      2     0      1.0     1.0
8       C      3     0      1.0     1.0
```

Finally we set 1 to all months greater or equals to `month_y` and 0 otherwise.

```py
df["pass_patch"] = np.where(
    df["month"].ge(df["month_y"]),
    1,
    0)
```

and we drop the columns we don't need anymore

```py
df = df.drop(columns=["month_y", "pass_y"])
```

Which returns

```sh
  student  month  pass  pass_patch
0       A      1     0           0
1       A      2     1           1
2       A      3     0           1
3       B      1     0           0
4       B      2     0           0
5       B      3     0           0
6       C      1     1           1
7       C      2     0           1
8       C      3     0           1
```

Comment: Thanks rpanai! That actually gives me an idea of another groupby problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I found the other answers amazing but if you are new to pandas I prefer a step-by-step solution so one can learn how to approach different problems.